# What does python code do and what does xml code do in odoo?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

And also explain what is osv.osv and sometimes why we include class name at last line in python code like this student(). Why do we need to do that?
And last what is arch field in xml code.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Python will give you functionalities(i.e. "Back end" Not DataBase) and XML will gives you the view(i.e "Front End").
- OSV = Object Service. Keeps the definitions of objects and their fields in memory, more or less.
- "arch" will give "View Architecture" for XML!

Answer (score 2):

If you have experience with MVC, then you can compare odoo python file to a model / controller which holds the business logic, for creating masters etc 
and a xml file to a view which is for presenting the data to the UI.

osv class inside in OSV module in OpenERP server , which contains all the OpenERP properties like you can see _column, _defaults and other many things.

student() - its like a constructor to invoke the object, but its not needed now in latest versions